# In WP7 TextBox.Focus() does not work when WebBrowser control is present on page

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, focus, browser

I need to set focus on the textbox. The problem is when a WebBrowser control is present on the page, the SIP is displayed as if textbox is selected, but cursor is not visible in textbox and the input does not go to the textbox.

If I comment the WebBrowser control out, then the behavior is as expected - cursor is blinking in the TextBox when page is loaded.

Here is the XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="WP7Sample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
Loaded="MainPageLoaded">

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox x:Name="txt"/>
    <phone:WebBrowser/>
</StackPanel>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And the codebehind:

```
void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txt.Focus();
}
```

I have tried the different workarounds, but no luck.
Namely I have tried to call SetFocus from the Load, NavigatedTo etc events. I have also tried to set focus to some other control and then back to the textbox, no luck either.

Could someone provide a workaround for this problem?

BTW, the problem is reproduced on the emulator, on HTC Mozart and Trophy devices all with NoDo update installed.

Comment: No answer I'm afraid - to me it looks like the native web browser control isn't playing nicely with the Silverlight framework.  Interestingly, the FocusManager thinks that the textbox has focus.  Even if you delay setting the focus by a couple of seconds using a DispatcherTimer, it still doesn't work... I'd file a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, looks like that, WebBrowser is stealing the focus.
I was able to find the similar post at apphub foru: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/70736/460811.aspx#460811. No answer too.

Comment: If I choose to add WebBrowser control later manually, then until it is added, the texbox has focus. As soon as WebBrowser is added, the TextBox looses focus and is not able to receive it back until the user clicks any control on the screen.
The same applies if I add TextBox manually - it cannot have focus until user clicks it.

Comment: I had the same problem as this, although bizarrely the WebBrowser control was on a different page to the TextBox I was trying to set focus on.  Ended up having to add/remove the WebBrowser control from the visual tree when navigating to/from the containing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have provided a hack for the case for pre-Mango versions of WP7, I had not checked the scenario beforehand.
The good news, guys!

In WP7 Mango the problem does not exist!

Answer (score 2):

step 1 : Bind loaded event with respective textbox where u want to set focus

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="2,0,2,0">
  <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" Height="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Loaded="SearchTextBox_Loaded"
           KeyDown="SearchTextBox_KeyDown"/>
</StackPanel>
```

step- 2: Now set Focus in when this event occurs

```
private void SearchTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    (sender as TextBox).Focus();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the txt.Focus() call twice.  I found this looking for a solution on how to set focus on a ListBox.  I ended up trying to call the Control.Focus() function twice to set the focus (firing 3 GotFocus events) and it seemed to work.

Comment: When your answer includes snippets of code inline with your text, please surround those snippets with backticks (`) for readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty workaround, but you could do this. On startup have the `WebBrowser` component absent from the page. Then, have the `TextBox` control wired to a `LostFocus` event. Something like this:

```
txt.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(txt_LostFocus);
```

When it loses focus, you can safely add a WebBrowser control to the page:

```
void txt_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new WebBrowser());
}
```

This won't let you re-focus programmaticlly later, as the `WebBrowser` will be inhibiting it, but it is a way to do it at startup.

Comment: Dennis, I have to see the TextBox with focus AND the WebBrowser control at once upon page load.
Your approach does not help me to fix the problem. As soon as I have WebBrowser on a page, TextBox loses focus. And could you please explain what is the supposed difference in adding the webbrowser control in LostFocus event? TextBox has already lost the focus already.

Comment: This method only works if you need the TextBox before the WebBrowser control. So that you focus on the TextBox and when it loses focus, you add the WebBrowser control.

Comment: I see, but alas, it does not help in my scenario when I have to see the WebBrowser and the textbox with focus. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling something in the GotFocus event. Maybe `txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;` It works for me.